# Proving a subgroup generated by a subset is a normal subgroup using universal properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, normal-subgroups, universal-property

I have the following (from Aluffi II.7.7):

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$ be generated by all elements of a fixed order $N$. Then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I came up with a fairly simple proof using the concrete description for "the subgroup generated by a subset": the subgroup consists of exactly the products of elements of the subset.

> *Proof:* Using the concrete description for $H$, any element $h \in H$ can be written as:
> $$ h = \prod_{1 \leq i < k} a_i,$$
> where each $a_i$ has order $N$. But for any $g \in G$, we know each $g a_i g^{-1}$ has order $N$ as well, so:
> $$ \prod_{1 \leq i < k} ga_ig^{-1} \in H,$$
> but this product is just $ghg^{-1}$. Therefore, $H$ is normal in $G$.

However, I was wondering if there's a proof that uses the following definition of "the subgroup generated by a subset":

> **Definition**:
> For any $A \subseteq G$ with the natural map $\iota: A \to G$, the universal property for free groups implies that there exists a unique $\varphi: F(A) \to G$ such that the following diagram commutes:
> [image: universal property for free groups]
> The subgroup generated by $A$ is then the image of $\varphi$.

One of my attempts is as follows:

> Let $G$ be a group, and let $A$ be the elements of order $N$ in $G$. For any $g \in G$, let $\gamma_g$ denote conjugation by $g$; consider the following diagram:
> [image: construction of phi_g]
> The universal property for free groups guarantees that $\varphi_g$ exists and is unique. However, we also have $\varphi: F(A) \to G$ from the definition of the subgroup generated by $A$:
> [image: addition of phi]
> ...

I'm convinced that $??? = \gamma_g$ makes the diagram commute, in which case for any $h \in \text{img }\varphi$, then $h = \varphi(a)$ for some $a \in F(A)$ and $$ghg^{-1} = \gamma_g(\varphi(a)) = \varphi(\varphi_g(a)).$$
Thus, $ghg^{-1} \in \text{img } \varphi$. I'm stuck on how to prove that $??? = \gamma_g$ with just universal properties. I tried invoking the universal property with $\varphi \, j \, \gamma_g : A \to G$ but couldn't seem to get anywhere. Does anyone have suggestions on how to proceed from here?

Comment: The map ??? is not unique though. Certainly $???=\gamma_g$ works, but so does $???=\gamma_h$, whenever $gh^{-1}$ (or $g^{-1}h$ if you act on the other side) centralizes all elements of order $N$. This can happen, most obviously in a direct product of groups of coprime order. You will probably need to assume that $G$ is generated by $A$ first, and then you have ruined your result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David pointed out in the comments, "proving that ??? $= \gamma_g$" is the wrong way to think about it.  In fact, there can be other endomorphisms of $G$ that make your diagram commute; for example, in the silly case $N = 1$, *any* endomorphism of $G$ makes the diagram commute.

Instead, I would go back to the definition of the morphism $\gamma_g:  A \to A$.  By definition, this is the restriction of $\gamma_g:  G \to G$ to the subset $A$.  It follows that the outer rectangle of your diagram commutes, with ??? = $\gamma_g$.  The problem then is to prove that the upper square commutes as well.  That is, we must show that $\gamma_g \varphi = \varphi \varphi_g:  F(A) \to G$.  By (the uniqueness part of) the universal property of free groups, it suffices to prove that $\gamma_g \varphi j = \varphi \varphi_g j:  A \to G$.  This follows from the commutativity of the bottom square and the outer rectangle.

Comment: Do you mean $\varphi \varphi_g j: A \to G$, not $\varphi_g \varphi j$?

Comment: Yes, fixed.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow why $\gamma_g \varphi j = \varphi \varphi_g j$ implies $\gamma_g \varphi = \varphi \varphi_g$. Are we applying the universal property to $\varphi \varphi_g j: A \to G$?

Comment: Yes.  The universal property says that there is exactly one map $F(A) \to G$ factoring the given map $A \to G$.  Both $\gamma_g \varphi$ and $\varphi \varphi_g$ factor this map, so they must be equal.

Comment: I see: the uniqueness in the universal property tells us $\alpha j = \alpha' j = \varphi j \gamma_g \implies \alpha = \alpha'$. Then we take $\alpha = \gamma_g \varphi$ and $\alpha' = \varphi \varphi_g$. Thanks for the help!